Nuxt 3 / Nuxt UI / Vuedraggable - Is it possible to reorder table rows in <UTable> using Vuedraggable?
I need to create a table with the possibility of reordering items via drag&drop but no idea if that's possible. I am using many v-slots to adjust the styling and content.
        <UTable
          v-model="selectedOneTimeCosts"
          :rows="sortedOneTimeItems"
          :columns="oneTimeCostColumns"
          class="w-full border border-neutral-200 mt-3 overflow-x-auto"
          :ui="{
            th: { base: 'sticky top-0' },
            wrapper: { base: '' },
          }"
        >
          <!-- Item Name Column -->
          <template v-slot:itemName-data="{ row }">
            <div
              @click="() => setEdit(row.id, 'itemName')"
              v-if="editItemId !== row.id || editField !== 'itemName'"
              :class="{'cell-filled': row.itemName}"
              class="cursor-pointer hover:bg-neutral-100 p-1.5 rounded w-full min-w-40 h-8 text-neutral-400"
            >
              {{ row.itemName || 'Title' }}
            </div>
            <UInput
              v-else
              :id="`input-${row.id}-itemName`"
              v-model="row.itemName"
              @blur="() => clearEdit(row.id)"
              placeholder="Title"
              class="focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500 rounded h-8"
            />
          </template>

          <!-- Notes Column -->
          <template v-slot:notes-data="{ row }">
            <div
              @click="() => setEdit(row.id, 'notes')"
              v-if="editItemId !== row.id || editField !== 'notes'"
              :class="{'cell-filled': row.notes}"
              class="cursor-pointer hover:bg-neutral-100 p-1.5 rounded border border-transparent min-w-56 w-auto h-8 text-neutral-400"
            >
              {{ row.notes || 'Notes' }}
            </div>
            <UInput
              v-else
              :id="`input-${row.id}-notes`"
              v-model="row.notes"
              @blur="() => clearEdit(row.id)"
              placeholder="Notes"
              :class="{'cell-filled': row.notes}"
              class="focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-1 focus:ring-blue-500 outline-none rounded min-w-56 w-auto h-8"
            />
          </template>

          <!-- Milestone Column -->
          <template v-slot:milestone-header>
            <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
              <span class="text-xs text-gray-500">Milestone</span>
              <UButton variant="solid" color="gray" size="xs" label="Edit" class="px-2 py-1" icon="i-heroicons-cog-6-tooth" @click="modalMilestonesOpen = true"/>
            </div>
          </template>

          <template v-slot:milestone-data="{ row }">
            <USelectMenu
              v-model="row.milestoneId"
              :options="truncatedMilestoneOptions"
              placeholder="Choose milestone"
              option-attribute="text"
              value-attribute="value"
              class="w-full p-1 rounded border-gray-300"
              :popper="{ placement: 'bottom-start', strategy: 'fixed', offsetDistance: 8 }"
              :uiMenu="{ width: 'w-48' }"
              @change="updateItems"
            >
              <template #option="{ option }">
                <div class="flex items-center">
                  <span
                    class="inline-block w-2 h-2 rounded-full mr-2"
                    :style="{ backgroundColor: option.color }"
                  ></span>
                  <span>{{ option.text }}</span>
                </div>
              </template>
              <template #selected="{ option }">
                <div class="flex items-center">
                  <span
                    class="inline-block w-2 h-2 rounded-full mr-2"
                    :style="{ backgroundColor: option.color }"
                  ></span>
                  <span>{{ option.text }}</span>
                </div>
              </template>
            </USelectMenu>
          </template>

          <template v-slot:time-data="{ row }">
            <div
              @click="() => setEdit(row.id, 'time')"
              v-if="editItemId !== row.id || editField !== 'time'"
              :class="{'cell-filled': row.time}"
              class="text-right cursor-pointer hover:bg-neutral-100 p-1.5 rounded border border-transparent w-20 h-8 text-neutral-400"
            >
              {{ row.time }}h
            </div>
            <UInput
              v-else
              :id="`input-${row.id}-time`"
              v-model.number="row.time"
              @blur="() => clearEdit(row.id)"
              @keydown.enter="() => clearEdit(row.id)"
              placeholder="1h"
              class="text-right focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-1 focus:ring-blue-500 outline-none rounded w-20 h-8"
              type="number"
              min="1"
            />
          </template>

          <!-- Cost Column -->
          <template v-slot:cost-header="{ row }">
            <div class="flex justify-end align-center text-right space-x-0.5">
              <span class="text-xs text-gray-500">Cost</span>
              <UTooltip v-if="proposal.useHourlyRate" text="Time x Your hourly rate" :popper="{ placement: 'top' }">
                <QuestionMarkCircleIcon class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-400/70 hover:text-gray-400 mr-[-4px]" />
              </UTooltip>
            </div>
          </template>

          <template v-slot:cost-data="{ row }">
            <div
              v-if="proposal.useHourlyRate"
              class="flex justify-end align-center text-right w-20 text-neutral-700 cursor-not-allowed"
            >
              ${{ formatNumber(row.time * userStore.hourlyRate) }}
            </div>
            <div
              v-else-if="editItemId !== row.id || editField !== 'cost'"
              @click="() => setEdit(row.id, 'cost')"
              :class="{'cell-filled': row.cost, 'cursor-pointer text-neutral-800 hover:bg-neutral-100': true}"
              class="text-right p-1.5 rounded border border-transparent w-20 h-8 text-neutral-800"
              :style="{ color: row.cost ? 'inherit' : '#404040' }"
            >
              ${{ typeof row.cost === 'number' ? formatNumber(row.cost) : '0.00' }}
            </div>
            <UInput
              v-else
              :id="`input-${row.id}-cost`"
              v-model="row.cost"
              @blur="() => clearEdit(row.id)"
              placeholder="$0.00"
              class="text-right  outline-none rounded w-20 h-8"
              type="number"
              style="height: 32px;"
            />
          </template>
          <template v-slot:actions-data="{ row }">
            <div class="text-right justify-end">
              <UButton @click="removeItem(row.id)" size="xs" variant="ghost" icon="i-heroicons-trash-16-solid" class="bg-transparent text-red-400 hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-red-500" />
            </div>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:empty-state>
            <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center py-16">
              <img src="~/assets/img/empty_state_costs.svg" alt="Empty state" />
              <span class="text-md text-gray-700 font-medium mt-4">Add first one-time cost</span>
              <span class="text-sm text-gray-500 font-regular mt-1">e.g. Single page, font family or paid plugin.</span>
              <div class="mt-5 space-x-3">
                <UButton @click="addOneTimeCost('one-time')" size="md" color="white" icon="i-heroicons-plus">Add cost</UButton>
              </div>
            </div>
          </template>
        </UTable>

I was trying to wrap the whole content of the table with <draggable> but had no success with the final effect. I can rebuild the entire thing with a regular table but just need to know if UTable allow me to reorder with Vuedragglable (or something else) or not.
Let me know if you need to see the scripts or something else.
